# python перебор словаря и списка через цикл

Tags: python

столкнулся с проблемой перебора входных данных и словаря.
Получается только выводить ключи(элементы), мне нужно получить значения.

```
dictionary = dict(яблоко=223.7, морковь=87.345,апельсин=1.98, кукуруза=16.443)               
data = ('яблоко', 'морковь', 'апельсин', 'кукуруза', 'яблоко', 'морковь', 'апельсин', 'кукуруза')                                                                                          
result = []                                                                                        
     for element in check :
if element in tonal :
    result.append(element)                                                               
print(result)
```

в данных элементы могут повторяться несколько раз, могут вообще отсутствовать. Как можно посчитать по значениям сумму?
Спасибо.

Comment: `sum(dictionary.values())` ?

Comment: У вас табуляция отклеилась

Comment: А что за загадочная "tonal" в вашем скрипте? Каковы его значения?